# Regular expression for finding JavaScript arrays in html document

Tags: c, regex

I want to search this [html](http://www.dict.cc/?s=fork) for these strings:

```
var c1Arr = new Array("","to fork","to fork","to fork","to fork","to fork","to fork","to fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork","fork-tongued","to fork off","to fork off","to fork out");
var c2Arr = new Array("","abbiegen","gabeln","abzweigen","aufspalten","sich gabeln","sich verzweigen","sich zwillen","Gabel","Gabelung","Abzweigung","Verzweigung","Aufspaltung","Abspaltung","Zwiesel","Gabel","Weggabelung","doppelzüngig","schräg abzweigen","schräg abbiegen","auszahlen");
```

I tried something like this: `"^[c1Arr = new Array(][-\\.~:%_/?A-Za-z0-9]*[);]$"` and some variations but this doesn't seem to work. I read a tutorial on how to build regular expressions but this didn't help much.

Any ideas on how a regex for these strings would look like?

Comment: Please format your text in a way, that a human can read it. Also please separate the *given* String and the part you want to match.

Comment: I want to match and get the entire string as i posted it.

Comment: Why do newbies use `[...]` as if it were a grouping parenthesis? This usage must come from some document or tutorial, the author of which should be duly punished.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: @verbose: because he's doing this in C. He's searching for JavaScript strings using his C program. At least that's how I understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
^var \w+ = new Array\(.*\);$
```

This will match the beginning of the string (or line in multi-line mode), followed a literal `var`, followed by one or more 'word' characters followed by a literal `= new Array(` followed by zero or more of any characters, followed by a literal `);` and the end of the string (or line in multi-line mode).

Comment: Escape the inner `)` also: `[^\)]*`

Comment: @dognose That's not necessary inside a character class, unless there are some peculiarities about the regex.h engine I'm not aware of. In any case since OP appears to want to match the entire line (given that the sample uses `^` and `$`), a `.*` seems easier.

Comment: Thx, this helped but there is always a third string in the html that starts with "var idArr", which i don't want, how can i specify this?

Comment: @Auberotte perhaps instead of `\w+` use `c\d+Arr`?

Comment: Ok, very dump question maybe but how do i highlight something in grey? (I don't want to get downvoted anymore)

Comment: I am using this solution: `"^var [a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+ = new Array\(.*\);$"` because i'm always getting warnings about the `\`

Comment: @Auberotte SO uses a modified version of [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) for formatting posts. When you are writing a question or answer there is an orange '?' button above the text area. It will provide detailed help for writing well-formatted posts. Comments use a limited subset of the Markdown syntax; you can click the 'help' button  under the 'Add Comment' for more info on formatting comments. Also see the help center: [**Markdown help**](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @Auberotte You need a slash for the regular expression, but you probably also need to escape the slash for the benefit of the C compiler. I believe the C-formatted string literal should look like `"^var \\w+ = new Array\\(.*\\);$"`, or using my other suggestion, `"^var c\\d+Arr = new Array\\(.*\\);$"`.